# How to requeue the messages when the spider has error with scrapy and Rabbitmq (pika)

Tags: python, scrapy, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to use pika and scrapy to run MQ, and let consumer call the spider. I have a `consumer.py` and a scrapy spider `spider.py`.

The spider is running in the consumer with the argument sent from producer. I use
`used_channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)`
to delete the message.

I expected the message would be deleted when the spider finishes the job, and if there's an error the message should be requeued. When the spider runs properly, everything looks fine; the message is deleted and the job is done. However, if there's an error happening when running the spider, the message is still got deleted and the job is not done but the messages missed.

I watched the Rabbitmq management UI, and I found the message became 0 when the spider was still running (the console hadn't showed the job was done yet).

I wonder is it because scrapy is asynchronous? So when this line `run_spider(message=decodebody)` is still running the next line `used_channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)` won't wait until the spider is done.

How can I fix this? I would like to delete the message after the spider is done the job properly.

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

setup() # for CrawlerRunner
settings = get_project_settings()

def get_message(used_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    decodebody = bytes.decode(body)

    try:
        run_spider(message=decodebody)
        used_channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)

    except: 
        channel.basic_reject(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)


def run_spider(message):
    crawler = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    crawler.crawl(MySpider, message=message)


while(True):
    try: 
        # blocking connection
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=rabbit_host))
        channel = connection.channel()
        # declare exchange, the setting must be same as producer
        channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange=rabbit_exchange,
            exchange_type='direct',  
            durable=True,            
            auto_delete=False        
        )
        # declare queue, the setting must be same as producer
        channel.queue_declare(
            queue=rabbit_queue, 
            durable=True, 
            exclusive=False,
            auto_delete=False
        )
        # bind the setting
        channel.queue_bind(
            exchange=rabbit_exchange,
            queue=rabbit_queue,
            routing_key=routing_key
        )

        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1) 
        channel.basic_consume(
            queue=rabbit_queue,
            on_message_callback=get_message,
            auto_ack=False
        )

        logger.info(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
        # start crawler
        channel.start_consuming()
    
    except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as err:
        print('ConnectionClosed error:', err)
        continue
    # Do not recover on channel errors
    except pika.exceptions.AMQPChannelError as err:
        print("Caught a channel error: {}, stopping...".format(err))
        break
    # Recover on all other connection errors
    except pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError as err:    
        print("Connection was closed, retrying...", err)
        continue
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure that it isn't just the same client that instantly consumes the rejected message?

Comment: Thank you @eandersson! I have found the solution, I have posted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone handle multithread with MQ for pika library. He uses `.is_alive` to check if the thread is done. So, I follow the idea. Scrapy is multithread, I add the return `crawler`, and check `crawler._active` before deleting the message.

[Source code for scrapy.crawler](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/crawler.html)

```py
def run_spider(news_info):
    # run spider with CrawlerRunner
    crawler = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    # run the spider script
    crawler.crawl(UrlSpider, news_info=news_info)

    return crawler
```

```py
crawler = run_spider(news_info=decodebody)
        
# wait until the crawler is done
while (len(crawler._active) > 0):
    time.sleep(1)

used_channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=basic_deliver.delivery_tag)
```